# Do Google App Engine charge my application for this action?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a Java chat app based on App Engine platform. The app will not store data into database but in a `public static variable`.

Ok, Now, here is the logic

A user can enter `chat.html` & post messages to server and the messages will be stored inside a `ConcurrentHashMap<User, List<String>`

Then `chat.html` will have a `checkLatestMsg()` function that runs every 3 secs. Thus function will read the `ConcurrentHashMap<User, List<String>` &

```
for(String s: list){
    if(s!=null && "".equals(s)){
        resp.setContentType("text/plain;charset=utf-8");
        resp.getWriter().println(s);
    }
  }
```

So the `resp.getWriter().println(s);` won't show anything the `list` has no data. My question is that:

*Will Google count the number of call requests?*

*What if we send a request but `resp.getWriter().println(s);` shows nothing, then will Google count that call?*

The Quota pages tell nothing about this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

**Could you clarify it?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your app won't work since static variables are not synced accross instances. Thus if more than a single instance runs - or if an instance is recycled - your chat log will go to oblivion.

Comment: it could work for some users, when manual scaling enabled and forced to 1 instance only, anyway it will have periodical loses of chat history, maybe just few times a day. I told topic started already, in another question, but seems that this is ok for this simple app

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Of course if you scale manually (and thus remove everything that makes using app engine worth it) that would work for a single instance. When you create a chat app though it's unlikely that you want to scale manually with a single instance. Automatic scaling is the default, and i doubt app engine beginners will start by messing around with the scaling options.

Comment: yeah, i agree that it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @konqi, how many times app engine syncs a day? 2-3 times? and you mean within that time we can not chat?, Who long does the sync take? 1 or 2 mins?

Comment: @Tom That's not what i meant. Static variables **will** **not** **sync**, **ever**. If you have multiple app engine instances (which you will have at some point) you will only ever see the variables of that particular instance. Your chats will be scattered and fragmented all over the place (instances). I suggest you use the datastore with caching in memcache for better performance. It's certainly doable, even though i never understood why people would want to build a chat application on app engine. Have a look at firebase (which is also a Google product), or other ready to use solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're no such thing as HTTP Call Quota. This will going to be billed by instance uptime (28 hours a day are free) and traffic (1Gb is free). Even if content of your response is empty, you'll have HTTP headers that will take some traffic.

Comment: Links: a) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Instances b) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests